# Password_verify bcrypt not working

Tags: php, passwords, prepared-statement

Thanks for helping me on this question. I am trying to compare the passwords with php password_verify but it is not working. Is there something wrong with my code? (i get the second message 'INVALID USER OR PASSWORD') Cheers!

```
function login_aut($uname, $pass){

     include('_con.php');
     include('password.php');

    $stmt = $conex->prepare("SELECT id, pass FROM tb_users WHERE uname =?");

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $uname);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* get num of rows */
    $stmt->store_result();
    $numrows = $stmt->num_rows;

    if(($numrows) == ""){echo 'INVALID USER ';die();}

    $stmt->bind_result($u_id,$upass);

    $stmt->fetch();
    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();



if (!password_verify($pass,$upass)) { echo 'INVALID USER OR PASSWORD'; die(); }
```

Comment: done any debugging, like `var_dump($pass, $upass)`? and `$numrows == ""` is invalid. num_rows returns an integer, you shouldn't be comparing to a string, even if `0 == ""` would be `true`.

Comment: also smells like variable scope

Comment: Thanks @MarcB var_dump is ok. =/

Comment: is `$upass` a hash, or a plaintext password or what?

Comment: and change `$stmt->execute();` to `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$conex->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` for potential db errors. Also make sure your column length is long enough for the hash. seen that happen often. Plus try it without the `login_aut()` function. could be a scope issue too.

Comment: I tested changing the variables name too but still the same @Fred-ii- . The mysql column is setup as varchar. Should it be a issue?

Comment: varchar is good but is it long enough to accomodate the hash? some set it to 50-60, which isn't long enough. I always set it to 255 and to accomodate for future and possible length increases.

Comment: It was the column length, omg! Sorry guys! @Fred-ii-

Comment: Yessssss!!! had a feeling about that. ;-)

Comment: which is what I originally stated in my [first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30598645/password-verify-bcrypt-not-working?noredirect=1#comment49266543_30598645). *"Also make sure your column length is long enough for the hash. seen that happen often."*

Comment: *Cheers* - Plus, you have a choice. You or I can submit an answer to close the question, or you can delete the question. It's up to you ;-) am just glad this was resolved. Otherwise, it will remain as unanswered where someone else may put in an answer, feeding off my comments. I don't appreciate vampires ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for helping guys! The problem was in the DB column length, it wasn't long enough for the hash. Thank you!